# Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o25.isBarrier. Trace: py4j.Py4JException: Method isBarrier([]) does not exist

Tags: pyspark, py4j

I am getting this error while using spark :
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o25.isBarrier. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method isBarrier([]) does not exist

version check and configuraion setup cross checked

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
sc = SparkContext()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
filepath = "D:\\DataScienceIntProgram\\spark\\a.us.csv"
us_stock = sc.textFile(filepath)
us_stock.take(10)
```

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o25.isBarrier. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method isBarrier([]) does not exist

Answer (score -1):

This issue is related to version mismatch of "sc.version", "sc._jsc.version()" and "conda list pyspark".

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: yes, the solution is - This issue is related to version mismatch of "sc.version", "sc._jsc.version()" and "conda list pyspark".